# Unity3D Android - Overlap Status Bar

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, status

I am developing an app for Android and iOS in Unity3D.

The app on iOS looks like this picture from the web (The status bar is transculent and overlaps the actual app): http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Dark-Navigation-Bar-Light-Status-Bar.jpg (I can't post images yet)

But when I run the app on Android, the status bar is drawn outside the app boundries. This means that the app gets stretched and it does not look satisfying: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2i1nvb8.jpg

Is it possible to make the Android status bar overlap the Unity3D app on Android? And if so, is it then possible to make it translucent as on iOS or at least a darker matching color (as introduced in Android 5.0.0)?

Best Regards,

Andreas B. Ostergaard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it lets you decide when to display the menu and navigation bars. Also lets you color them.

http://zehfernando.com/2015/unity-tidbits-changing-the-visibility-of-androids-navigation-and-status-bars-and-implementing-immersive-mode/

Comment: You should include relevant parts of code in your answer. Because when linked content disappears, your question becomes worthless.